# Is innodb compression compatible with full text search and is the memory compressed too?

Tags: compression, mariadb, innodb

I wan't to know if full text search can be used in compressed innodb tables, and if the compression will reduce both memory and disk usage or only disk, and i there is a performance impact using the compression.

Answer (score 1):

"Compatibility" is easily answered by trying in a tiny table.  I *think* it is compatible because the data is uncompressed whenever it comes into the buffer_pool.

"Compressed" is likely to save *disk* space, but the numbers I have heard are only 2x.  Ordinary text usually compresses 3x, but InnoDB has headers, etc, that are not compressed.  (JPG does not compress.)

As for reducing memory (buffer_pool) -- It is likely to consume extra memory because both the compressed and uncompressed copies of the data are in memory at least some of the time.

A reference:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-compression-internals.html , plus pages around it.

My *opinion* is that InnoDB's compressed is rarely useful.  Instead, I recommend compressing and decompressing individual columns in the *client*, thereby offloading that CPU task from the *server*.  But that would not work for `FULLTEXT`, so maybe it would be useful for *your application*.